# jQuery while loop not waiting for animation

Tags: jquery, animation, while-loop

I have a jQuery function that does a `.clone()` on an object, and then an `.insertAfter()` and a `.slideDown()` on the cloned object. This whole function is wrapped inside a `while` loop. I will keep this as short and concise as possible and show a generic example:

```
while (statement) {
    // code for clone and insert  ...
    $("#newly_created_object").slideDown(500);
}
```

How can I prevent the next while-loop from firing before the `.slideDown()` animation (or any other kind of animation for that matter) ends ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I added an explicit termination condition to my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to create and insert all of the elements first, storing them in an array.  Then you can use a recursive function to pop one element off the array and animate it, calling your function on the remaining elements in the callback handler for the animation -- to ensure that the first is complete before the next starts.

```
    ...
    var elems = [];
    while (statement) {
        var elem = ...clone and insert element, returning element...
        elems.push(elem);
    }

    animateElems( elems);
}


function animateElems( elems )
{
    if (elems.length > 0) {
        var elem = elems.shift();
        $(elem).slideDown( 500, function() {
             animateElems( elems );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: by far the most elegant solution

Comment: Agreed, simply brilliant ! I really appreciate it, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You have to make the animation synchronous, but that is not a good idea, as it will block the browser and annoy the user. Here is another question on that topic: [JQuery synchronous animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594077/jquery-synchronous-animation)

A better idea is to use the callback function, which will be executed when the animation is done. Like so:

```
function cloneAndInsert(elm){
  if(statement){
    // code for clone and insert
    $("#newly_created_object").slideDown(500, function(){
      cloneAndInsert(elm);
    });
  }
}
```

This code will call itself when it is done with one object (recursively).

Comment: I was going to go ahead with your solution, but with tv's solution I merely need to add a few lines, rather than rewriting my function which is much more complex than the generic example I gave above. Nevertheless, thanks, your input was much appreciated as well !

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution, unless you want to avoid [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake), is to use jQuery's [`queue()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/queue#namecallback) and [`dequeue()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/dequeue#name) functions:

```
while (statement) {
  var elem = ... clone and insert element, returning element ...

  $(document).queue((function (el) {
    return function () {
      el.slideDown(function () { $(document).dequeue(); });
    }; 
  })(elem));
}
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/axafo (editable via: http://jsbin.com/axafo/edit#javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if element is still being animated like that:

```
while (statement) {
    if ($("#newly_created_object").is(":animated")) continue;
    $("#newly_created_object").slideDown(500);
}
```

Although it may not be the best solution, because you will keep user browser busy.

The correct way to do actions after animation is finished:

```
$("#newly_created_object").slideDown(500, function () {
    alert('this alert box appears when animation is finished');
});
```