# run another function after preceding function has completed?

Tags: javascript

if i fire up 2 functions like this:

```
prepare_data();
read_data();
```

then i guess they are running at the same time. but as you can see function two is depending on the first one, so how can i make the latter one run after the first one is completed?

Comment: What makes you think they are running at the same time?

Comment: i just thought they were...but its good that they dont, just like in php:)

Comment: but if you got 2 jquery event handlers on one DOM element. lets say $(a).click... which one will run first? the one above or do they run at the same time?

Comment: I believe that they will run in the order that they were added.  They will not run simultaneously.

Comment: As always, the lesson here is: **try it** before you wonder what the behavior will be.

Comment: @SLaks: FYI order of event handlers is non-deterministic in all browsers today. DOM 3's `EventListenerList` is meant to address this http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20010823/events.html#Events-EventListenerList

Comment: @Crescent: jQuery event handlers are not DOM event handlers.  I believe that they will be triggered in the `for in` traversal order of the `handlers` list.

Comment: @SLaks: "jQuery event handlers are not DOM event handlers" - That does not compute. What?

Comment: @Crescent: jQuery adds a single event handler which loops over an internal queue.  It does not add each handler separately to the browser's DOM event.

Comment: @SLaks: you're right, I missed the "jquery" in the OPs comment about multiple event handlers. My comments were specifically targeted at pure `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` implementations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Javascript, and most other languages, run code sequentially.

Therefore, they will *not* both run at the same time.

In fact, it is not possible to run two different pieces of Javascript code at the same time.  However, in many other languages, it is possible using threads.

However, if they make AJAX calls, the corresponding server-side code called by both functions will run simultaneously.
To prevent that, you'll need to make the first function accept a callback parameter and pass it the second function.

Comment: I'd just get rid of "and most other languages" there. Way too sweeping a remark....

Comment: Do you disagree?  Are there any languages which execute every statement in parallel?

Comment: @SLaks: nice strawman comeback there ;) All I meant was the sentence is kind of non-specific and slightly mis-leading there. Your stuff about threads and callbacks is what I think you were getting at.

Comment: @SLaks: I disagree! In multi treaded applications you can execute statements in parallel.  In such a system this question is very valid.  May be this user knows more about programming than he reveals :)

Comment: I'm well aware that it's possible; see my fourth sentence. However, I don't think there are any languages which have the behavior that he's expecting. (Where two ordinary sequential lines of code will run in parallel by default)

Comment: It's possible to run two or more different pieces of JavaScript code in the same script at the same time using window.setTimeout(..) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout and related functions.

Comment: @jdk: no, `setTimeout` simply queues execution. JavaScript is single threaded (in the browser). By definition it cannot execute more than one statement at the exact same moment in time.

Comment: @Crescent: Very true.  It is a common misconception that `setTimeout` will escape the browser's UI thread; in reality, it **will not**.   (And therefore, Javascript developers never need to worry about thread safety) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594077/jquery-synchronous-animation

Comment: Note that Firefox 3.5 does support multi-threading: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers, as does Google Gears: http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_workerpool.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming the first call makes some kind of asynchronous call that the second relies upon because otherwise the two functions will execute sequentially.

If so you need to do the second in the callback from the first. For example, in jQuery:

```
function prepare_data() {
  $("#data").load("/load_data.php", function() {
    read_data();
  });
}
```

It's impossible to say how you should solve this without more information on whether you're using vanilla Javascript or a particular library. I'd strongly suggest using a library of some sort for AJAX however.

Answer (score 3):

May be you want to call Second function after first function function to be successfully executed, if so, then you can do this by this

```
$('button').click(function()
{
    function1(someVariable, function() {
       function2(someOtherVariable);
    });
});


function function1(param, callback) {
  alert('Now first function will be called.');
  callback();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@SLaks

> In fact, it is not possible to run two
>   different pieces of Javascript code at
>   the same time. However, in many other
>   languages, it is possible using
>   threads.

Is this completely correct? cant you run javascript parallely using web workers ?

http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-workers-20090423/

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers

Comment: In IE, it is.  In Firefox, it isn't.