# Calling a function after another one has successfully ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I'd like to call a javascript (with jQuery) function after one has completely ended.

I know there's a way to do it using the $.ajax() function with the 'success:' parameter. Is there a way to do the same thing without using the $.ajax() function ?

For example if I had :

```
var test = function()
{
    alert('Hello !');
}

var test_check = function()
{
    alert('Hello has been displayed successfully');
}
```

Would there be a way to call test(); and then test_check() ONLY after test() has actually been completed ?

Comment: This heavily depends on your usage of asynchronous tasks. If you don't have anything async, just call your functions one after the other. If you are having async operations they will probably supply you with a callback parameter.

Comment: This might help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937970/run-another-function-after-preceding-function-has-completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work

```
test();
test_check();
```

`test_check` will execute after `test` finishes executing.

Comment: -1 That has nothing to do with the fact that Javascript is a single threaded language. The same applies to multi threaded languages also.

Answer (score 1):

The function will return when it has completed, so you just call the next function after it:

```
test();
test_check();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = function()
{
    alert('Hello !');
    test_check(); /* call test_check() at the very end of test() */
}
```