# jQuery .unload() ignores fadeOut and skips away

Tags: jquery, fadeout

First of all, sorry for the double question, but I feel this is a rather different manner.

I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#container').fadeOut(0);
        $('#container').fadeIn(500);

        $(window).unload(function(){
            alert("Hello.");
            $('#container').fadeOut(500);
        });
    });
```

It should show up the page by fading it in, and make it unload by fading it out. Though, when I quit the page or submit the form that's in it, I only see the alert, but after I press OK on it, the page just disappears and the next one appears. The fade isn't executed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Better: `$('#container').hide().fadeIn(500);`

Comment: What you need is a synchronous fade out. `fadeOut` alone won't do it because it's asynchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything called in unload needs to be synchronous. I believe the `fadeOut` method calls a number of async callbacks. So when you call `fadeOut`, a number of callbacks are setup for later to make the animation. However, unload doesn't wait.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594077/jquery-synchronous-animation) to build the animation yourself.

Comment: @Jordan The question is: "How can I fix this?"

Comment: That should work, but how can I make the animation execute only when an unload is needed? Putting the animation inside an unload call will give the same result.

Comment: I don't know how to make animate work synchronously. I think you're going to have to write your own function that changes the opacity.

Comment: Yes but I'd still need a way to catch when a page needs to unload without actually unloading it until I'm done.

Comment: Anything you put inside the function passed to `unload` will be ran in order. So as long as you don't call an async function, you don't need worry about it. Basically you need a bunch of these in order.. `$('#container').css('opacity','0.9')` each one with a lesser opacity. You should cache the jQuery element in a variable though, so you're not transversing the DOM every time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ***[, complete ]*** callback for this now (1.0+):

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-complete