# jQuery .text() is too slow (callback possible?)

Tags: jquery

I've written a tooltip plugin for jQuery which displays a tooltip with a specified text whenever the user hovers over the element. By default, the tip shows to the top-right of the cursor, but if the tooltip is too wide to fit on the page, it shows instead to the top-left. The problem I'm having is that, after using .text(), I need to check the new width of the tooltip to see if it is wider than the window width, but there seems to be a delay such that the new width isn't set until after I've already called .width(). So, for example, the tooltip starts as an empty div, and even though I call .text() prior to .width(), by the time I call .width(), the div is still at width 0. Here is the code I've been using:

```
$.fn.tooltip = function(tText) {
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).unbind('.tipE').bind('mouseenter.tipE', function(e) {
            $('#toolTip')
                .hide()
                .stop(true, true)
                .text(tText)
                .positionAtCursor(e)
                .fadeIn('fast');
        }).bind('mouseleave.tipE', function() {
            $('#toolTip').fadeOut('fast');
        }).bind('mousemove.tipE', function(e) {
            $('#toolTip').positionAtCursor(e);
        });
    });
};

$.fn.positionAtCursor = function(e) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var top  = e.pageY - 25;
        var left = e.pageX + 10;

        var rightBound = $(window).width();
        if (rightBound && (e.pageX + $(this).width() > rightBound)) {
            left = e.pageX - $(this).width() - 20;
        }

        $(this).css({ 'top' : top, 'left' : left });
    });
};
```

Is there any way I can have a callback for the .text() so that I can wait to call positionAtCursor() ? Or is there some other flaw in my code that I've been missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was actually an issue with 'mousemove' being called prior to 'mouseenter'. So, since the text isn't set until 'mouseenter', the width appeared to be 0 the first time positionAtCursor was called. It seems to be working fine now that I have added ':visible' to the selector in 'mousemove':

```
$('#toolTip:visible').positionAtCursor(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.text(tText).positionAtCursor(e)` try:

```
.html(
   function(index,oldhtml){
      $(this).html(tText);
      if($(this).html()!==oldhtml){ $(this).positionAtCursor(e); } 
   });
)
```

May be a fairly crude method but perhaps that will work.

I suppose you could also have

```
while($(this).html()==oldhtml){ $(this).html(tText); }
$(this).positionAtCursor(e);
```

Comment: Would the first solution never call positionAtCursor since the current HTML will always be different than the old HTML (unless, as you also suggested, you loop it) ? Having a while loop concerns me in that it may cause some hang, although I suppose the delay is so small that that there should not be a noticeable delay. Hopefully there is a more straightforward approach.

Comment: I haven't tried using this but I am assuming oldhtml is the html in the element before you set the new html. Therefore, if it hasn't updated yet, the current html will be the same as the old html.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem.

SOLUTION is here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2716286/1238317

you should use `dequeue()`:

```
 $('#toolTip')
    .hide()
    .stop(true, true)
    .queue( YOUR_DEQUEUED_FUNCTION() )
    .positionAtCursor(e)
    .fadeIn('fast');
```

Where:

```
YOUR_DEQUEUED_FUNCTION = function() {
$(this).dequeue();
$('#toolTip').text(tText);
// ANY OTHER CODE BEFORE NEXT THINGS EXECUTED :)
}
```