# Return from a parent function when a callback is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In JavaScript, is it possible to return a value from a parent function from within a jquery callback function?

```
function thingsLoaded() {
 $("#loadingSplash").fadeOut( 1000, function() { //return thingsLoaded here    });
}
```

I've read some questions on here regarding Async vs Sync for AJAX callbacks? Does the same apply for this?

Also, I do not need to pass any variables, it's more just a timing thing to return from the thingsLoaded function once the fadeOut is completed.

**EDIT:** Clarification: I would like to delay returning from the thingsLoaded function, until the fadeOut callback function is complete.

Comment: you want to return the **thingsLoaded** from the fadeOut's callback or do you want to return the **value of thingsLoaded**? It's rather confusing...can you make the question clearer?

Comment: What do you want to do?  Returning from the `fadeOut` callback won't do anything.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594077/jquery-synchronous-animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, (I think you want to return *from* `thingsLoaded` in the callback, rather than actually returning `thingsLoaded` itself) then no.

The `thingsLoaded` function will return `undefined` before the callback is executed. If you have code that is dependent on the animation being finished, it has to go inside the callback. This is because `fadeOut` is asynchronous.